# sfdx force:source:deploy to a namespace org needs process builders to have namespace in all fields in xml file

Tags: salesforcedx, namespace

I am trying to deploy a process builder from a packaging org to another org where the package is installed created out of same packaging org. sfdx force:source:deploy -m "Flow:Change_C1" -u sfdxmove is failing. I am only able to successfully deploy when i change the xml content of the file by adding namespace prefix to every object, fields & invocable apex class. 
Is there a neat way to achieve this.
This is lot of manual work or probably I have to create a script.

Also, page layouts are getting deployed only by renaming the sfdx source file & adding namespace prefix.

Thanks